# Get n number of child elements

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two tables: `Blog` and `Post`. The blog table can have many posts.

I would like to get a blog with corresponding posts, but I would like to get only if there are 4 posts per blog and get only 4 posts. Moreover, after that, I would like to map the result to my model using Automapper:

```
return _context.Blogs
               .Include(x => x.Posts)
               .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Posts.Count >= 4)
               .ProjectTo<BlogVm>();
```

The `BlogVm` contains the same properties as `Blog` entity (the same is with Post). I'm using EntityFrameworkCore.

So do you have any idea how can I handle this?

Update:
The code returns all posts per blogs not only 4.
I would like to get blogs having minimum 4 posts and load only 4 posts.

Comment: I don't understand. What the trouble ? You already have a solution no ? Your code doesn't work ?

Comment: What is not working? Are there any errors you're countering?

Comment: I have updated my posts. What is wrong. Basically, the result contains all posts per blogs.

Comment: It's confusing, you want only blogs they have exactly 4 posts, OR you want blogs having minimum 4 posts and load only 4 posts ?

Comment: @GGO I would like to get blogs having minimum 4 posts and load only 4 posts.

Comment: Ok I delete my answer so, it is not suitable for your request, try Scott answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var postsFromBlogsWithAtLeastFourPosts =
    blogs.Where(blog => blog.Posts.Count() >= 4)
        .Select(blog => blog.Posts.Take(4))
        .ProjectTo<BlogVm>();
```

First select blogs with four or more posts. Then select four posts from each of those blogs.

Or did you want a total of four posts from blogs that have four or more posts (one post per blog)?

```
var postsFromBlogsWithAtLeastFourPosts =
    blogs.Where(blog => blog.Posts.Count() >= 4)
        .Take(4)
        .Select(blog => blog.Posts.First())
        .ProjectTo<BlogVm>();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it works ( never tested ), but you should use Take in your include :

```
return _context.Blogs
               .Include(x => x.Posts.Take(4))
               .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Posts.Count >= 4)
               .ProjectTo<BlogVm>();
```

Comment: I believe you can't use `Take` in that context and it should be between the `Where()` and the `ProjectTo`

Comment: No, It doesn't work. Message = "The property expression 'x => {x.Posts => Take(4)}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score -1):

Try this (except mapping to your model):

```
var q = (
        from blog in _context.Blogs
        from post in blog.Posts
        group blog by new
                      {
                          BlogId = blog.Id,
                          PostId = post.Id,
                          PostText = post.Text,
                      }
        into g
        where g.Count() >= 4
        select new 
               { 
                   g.Key.BlogId, 
                   g.Key.PostId, 
                   g.Key.PostText 
               }
        ).Take(4);
```

Or similar:

```
var q1 = _context.Blogs.SelectMany(blog => blog.Posts, (blog, post) => new { blog, post })
                       .GroupBy(@t => new { BlogId = blog.Id, PostId = post.Id, PostText = post.Text }, @t => blog)
                       .Where(g => g.Count() >= 4)
                       .Select(g => new { g.Key.BlogId, g.Key.PostId, g.Key.PostText })
                       .Take(4);
```

There is error. It would take only 4 rows from result. Without Take(4) it will give you all blogs there are minimum 4 posts per blog.